# Docker MongoNetworkError: connection timed out when build Node JS App by docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Cann't connect to Mongodb. That installed by Docker

```
let dbRoute = "mongodb://mongo:27017/kgp_news"

const option = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
    useNewUrlParser: true 
};

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, option)
```

I install mongo by docker. It run port 27017.

And when I run project by script "node index.js". it is working.

But when I build app by write Dockerfile. Cann't connect to Mongo.
`MongoNetworkError: connection timed out`

```
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/api_kgp/docker_build/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at connect (/api_kgp/docker_build/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at makeConnection (/api_kgp/docker_build/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/api_kgp/docker_build/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/api_kgp/docker_build/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
(node:20) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `mongo` in node.js server, can you `ping mongo` ? and telnet to port `27017`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan i try and this result: PING mongo.com (54.173.82.137) 56(84) bytes of data. It seem working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mongo` were installed on `container` so please make sure:

1. Expose `27017` port when you run to build `container`,

   `docker run -p 27017:27017 ....`
2. In `node` code, connect to `mongo` container using : IP address gateway of container network is `172.17.0.1:27017`

So:

`let dbRoute = "mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/kgp_news"`

Comment: Yes. It's woking now. Thank you very much. So now when connect with any container of docker using this "172.17.0.1", right?

Comment: yes, that's right ! its differ from port as belong to service

Comment: But docker documentation says you can use dns alias if the containers are under the same __user defined__ bridge network.

Answer (score 0):

use `localhost` of the docker container is running.

```
let dbRoute = "mongodb://localhost:27017/kgp_news"

const option = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
    useNewUrlParser: true 
};

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, option)
```

Or, you can put the IP address of mongodb condtiner. To get IP off mongodb conatiner use `$ docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID`

```
let dbRoute = "mongodb://<MONGODB_IP_ADDRESS>:27017/kgp_news"

const option = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
    useNewUrlParser: true 
};

mongoose.connect(dbRoute, option)
```

Comment: then put the IP of docker container running. however this ip will change everytime you  start you mongodb container.